# How to specify value for key in JSON map (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, key

I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. So using this code:

```
var myMap = {};
var keyVal = "abc";
var objVal = "123";
myMap.keyVal = objVal;
```

Now what I want to return is a JSON object that looks like `{"abc":"123"}` but instead it returns `{"keyVal":"123"}`. How can I get it to use the actual variable contents for the key instead of the variable name? (or really I guess it's not using the variable at all, just treating 'keyVal' as the key name)

Comment: If key is variable and unknown, how would u access its value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/):

```
myMap[keyVal] = objVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var datajson = JSON.parse(data);
        var keyArr = Object.keys(datajson);
        for ( var i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
            var val = datajson[keyArr[i]];
            }
```

Comment: Please refer the docs for formatting an answer. It would be really helpful to you to format future answers. Better formatted answers have higher rate of acceptance.

Answer (score -1):

```
var keyVal = "abc";
var objVal = "123";
eval("myMap." + keyVal + "='" + objVal + "'")
```

An alternative, but **eval is not recommended**

Comment: `eval("myMap." + keyVal)` probably returns `undefined`, and should result in an Invalid Lefthand Assignment error in the context you used it in. What you wanted to write was `eval("myMap." + keyVal + '="' + objVal + '"')`, but that is just as wrong for different reasons.

Comment: Oops yes eval("myMap." + keyVal + '="' + objVal + '"') is right syntax